# How to merge two dataframes based on a common column but duplicated values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with same columns but different data. One is the sample dataset which consists of 20,000 entries and the other is the control dataset with 1,093,564 entries. I want to extract the same amount of records from control dataset which have the same journal name as in the sample dataset but unique articles(title).

df1:

```
journal title
foo abs
bar abc
baz ghj
foo jkl
baz mnj
```

df2:

```
journal title
bar nko
foo cvb
foo yui
baz sdf 
bar hyt
foo kdm
baz bnd
baz lko
foo mnx
bar sdm
baz rty
```

The journal names are same in the both datasets but titles are unique and different in df1 from df2. I want something like this in the result:

```
journal title_x title_y
foo abs cvb
bar abc nko
baz ghj sdf
foo jkl kdm
baz mnj bnd
```

Comment: Please create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You probably need to `merge` these 2 datasets with `how=left`, but it's hard to actually help you without some example. Can you reduce your problem to 2 datasets that contain some very small subset of your data and show them to us?

Comment: Do you think `How to merge two dataframes based on a common column but duplicated values?` ? Removed `no`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join, but first is necessary create counter column for merging with remove consecutive duplicated values in `df2['journal']` with compare by not equal shifted values:

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('journal').cumcount()
df2 = df2[df2['journal'].ne(df2['journal'].shift())]
df2['g'] = df2.groupby('journal').cumcount()

df = df1.merge(df2, on=['journal','g'], how='left').drop('g', axis=1)
print (df)
  journal title_x title_y
0     foo     abs     cvb
1     bar     abc     nko
2     baz     ghj     sdf
3     foo     jkl     kdm
4     baz     mnj     bnd
```

Comment: works like a charm. I was stuck on it for days, stay blessed man!

Comment: @TabKey - Thank you, it was a bit complicated like only `merge`, but thank you for perfect sample data :)

Comment: i think i should edit the question statement too. what do you say? @jezrael

Comment: I think merge by duplicated values should be nice ;)